# Толкование глагола "пропустить"

Tags: семантика

Здравствуйте, уважаемые редакторы!

В процессе изучения диспозиции статьи  14.1 Правил дорожного движения установлено, что отсутствует понятие глагола "пропустить": " Водитель транспортного средства, приближающегося к нерегулируемому пешеходному переходу <*>, обязан снизить скорость или остановиться перед переходом, чтобы пропустить пешеходов, переходящих проезжую часть или вступивших на нее для осуществления перехода.(цитата в ред. Постановления Правительства РФ от 10.05.2010 N 316)", тогда как в статье 1.2 данного нормативно-правового акта глагол "уступить" правоприменителям разъясняется: "Уступить дорогу (не создавать помех)" - требование, означающее, что участник дорожного движения не должен начинать, возобновлять или продолжать движение, осуществлять какой-либо маневр, если это может вынудить других участников движения, имеющих по отношению к нему преимущество, изменить направление движения или скорость."

Пожалуйста, разъясните:

1. тождественны ли по смыслу оба глагола (пропустить-уступить), являющиеся достаточно важными понятиями для правильной квалификации действий субъекта, в отношении которого ведется административное расследование
2. каков смысл (семантическое значение) глагола "пропустить" в контексте ст.14.1 Правил дорожного движения

Заранее благодарны. Столярова О.С., Темников А.Г.

Answer (score 1):

Уступить можно *свое* место, то есть, грубо говоря, подвинуться, пропустить же - не сходя со своего места дать возможность оппоненту двигаться по собственной траектории. В этом и разница.
То есть, когда Вы *пропускаете* пешехода, Вы, например, останавливаетесь перед "зеброй" и даете ему пройти. Когда же Вы *уступаете* ему дорогу, Вы отъезжаете в сторону и даете ему пройти там, где сами находились до этого.
Надеюсь, удалось понятно объяснить.